# How to display function arguments in Spyder?

Tags: python, user-interface, editor, spyder

I'm using Spyder 2.2.5 with Python 2.7 and I want the editor to display the arguments of the function I'm calling after I type the first parenthesis. I know it's possible, because I can see it in the video-tutorials I'm using. I've tried (at least I think so..) all menu-items.
Getting crazy here, please help!

Comment: Please check you have all the necessary dependencies (see help menu), and turn on the options in preferences->editor->code introspection. Also note that spyder is now at 2.3.1 .

Comment: @mdurant: many thanks, I found it: I have to (figure out how to) install the module rope...

Answer (score 20):

I have a similar problem. The arguments pop-up shows up only until I start typing, so I have a problem if I forget what the latter arguments are. A workaround is to move the cursor on the function and press `Ctrl` + `i`. It shows the function documentation in help window, including its definition.

Answer (score 19):

You can activate the [object inspector](https://pythonhosted.org/spyder/inspector.html) to display the documention of the function itself by enabling automatic connections for your editor or console. It will then show you the function parameters as you press the left parenthesis.

To enable it go to Tools > Preferences > Object Inspector . Under Help-> Automatic connections check your desired programming environment and enable plug-in.

Comment: The link is dead and the feature not findable in the menus. Is it still possible in Spyder 3.2.

Comment: For those who are looking for the updated information. You can now find the connections settings under Tools > Preferences > Help > Automatic Connections. They moved "Help" up in the hierarchy. You can find more information [at this relevant StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40645942/spyder-missing-object-inspector).

Answer (score 8):

**For Spyder 3:**

*Tools > Preferences > Help > Automatic Connections* and then tick all the workspaces you want it to show functions' arguments.

Answer (score 0):

Go to *View > Window layouts > Spyder Default Layout*. This resets the Spyder IDE to the defaults, and the object inspector will function again (worked for me).

Answer (score 0):

Tools > Reset Spyder to factory defaults

it fixed my problem

Answer (score -1):

often would need to restart Spyder to have the inline help

Comment: This is not an answer it should be a comment

Answer (score -2):

Install kite from tools menu, which will resolve your issue